# Is anyone here tried connecting a Biometric fingerprint device with a web or desktop application?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, fingerprint

I am trying to connect a biometric device (ZKTeco) with a React web app. Is anyone has done this before? or what is the best way to connect a biometric device(Fingerprint scanner) to an application?

Thank you

I haven't tried it yet. I want get some idea before implement the system.

Comment: Before posting your question, it's beneficial to search on Google or Stack Overflow first to see if similar queries have been resolved. Experiment with various methods on your own. If you're still stuck, when asking for help, remember to describe what you've attempted, what succeeded, and what failed. This detail helps others provide targeted assistance. I found some resources and tutorials online by searching; you'll likely find the guidance you need by doing the same.